# Set background image from db

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to set the background image programatically?

I know how this can be done using css however this sets and fixes the background image. I have a model of books each with an image of the book and I would like to set the background to the book's image when the user fetches the book record.

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @image = @book.image
  # set the background image to @image
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your view (ex. `show.html.erb` or `index.html.erb` ):

```
<style media="screen">
  .image_div { background-image: url(<%= @book.image %>); }
</style>
```

`@book.image` needs to return the actual **path** to the image of `@book` object, you'll need to access whatever property stores the path `@book.image.path` or `@boook.image.url` or whatever fits your codebase

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```css
#pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="pic">
```